# Showing that $|X| \equiv |\text{Fix}(G)|\pmod{p}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, p-groups

$\newcommand{\fix}{\text{Fix}}$
$\newcommand{\stab}{\text{stab}}$
$\newcommand{\orb}{\text{Orb}}$
**Definition:** Let $G$ act on  a set $X$. We define $\fix(G) =\{x \in X : g \ast x = x, \forall g \in G\}$; i.e all elements of $X$ fixed by every $g \in G$.

**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$. Then $|\fix(G)| \equiv |X|\pmod{p}$.

> *Attempt:*
> To start, we know that $X$ is partitioned into it's orbits and since $G$ is finite we can use orbit-stabilizer theorem to assert that
> $$
>  \frac{|G|}{|\stab(x)|} = |\orb(x)|, \; (\forall x \in X).
>  $$
> Because $\stab(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is finite; Lagrange's theorem implies that $|\stab(x)|$ divides the order of $G$, but since $G$ is a $p$-group this means that $|\stab(x)|$ is a power of $p$, and further that for each $x \in X$, $|\orb(x)| = p^\alpha$ for some $\alpha \geq 0$. Next let us consider what it means to be an element of the fixed set of $G$. By definition, $x \in \fix(G)$ means that $g \ast x = x$ for all $g \in G$; which with some thought, means that $\orb(x) = \{x\}$, and moreover $|\orb(x)| = 1$. In light of this, we may write
> $$
>  \fix(G) = \{x \in X : |\orb(x)| = 1\},
>  $$
> and so $|\fix(G)|$ is just the number of elements of $X$ with just themselves in their orbit.
> Again as a corollary of Orbit-Stabilizer and that $X$ is a finite set, we know
> $$
>  |X| = \sum_{x \in X} |\orb(x)|.
>  $$
> But this gives more, reducing this sum modulo $p$ will annihilate any term such that $|\orb(x)| = p^\alpha$ where $\alpha>0$, and leave only terms whose orbits have $|\orb(x)| = 1$ (there are no other possible remainders because the orbits each have order a power of $p$ by the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem). But there are exactly $|\fix(G)|$ of those terms and hence $|X| \equiv |\fix(G)|\pmod{p}$.

Is this argument alright? Particularly is there a need for a more rigorous way to articulate the last paragraph? It felt slightly hand-wavy to me. Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof seems 90% correct to me. The end is not as hand-wavy as you think, however the fault lies in your sum "$|X| = \sum_{x \in X} |\operatorname{Orb}(x)|$" not being correct. You sum too many $x$, you want to only take one $x$ from each orbit, or equivalently to name your orbits $O_1,\dots,O_s$ for example and sum on $k \in \{1,\dots,s\}$.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! For some reason I thought that because they're equivalence classes they would get absorbed; no idea why I thought that. We can also say that since $X$ is finite that there are a finite number of orbits too, so I could just let $N$ be the number of orbits under the action from the start right? Then write it as $|X| = \sum_{i=1}^N \text{orb}(x_i)$ where $x_i$ are elements of the respective orbits.

Comment: Yeah that'll work just fine! (by the way I made an error in my second comment, I really don't know why I put $|G|$ at the top of the sum... oops. Though technically the sum still works since there wouldn't be orbits that big I suppose)

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the help @BrunoB, if you write either comment as an answer I'll accept it just to remove this from unanswered. Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the end "better" or in another way at least, I guess you can introduce, say, $r_i$ the number of orbits of cardinal $p^i$, and note that from a previous observation: $r_0=|\operatorname{Fix}(G)|$.
Then, by what you said earlier, those are the only possible cardinals for our orbits, and thus, if we note $|G| =: p^\beta$:
$$|X| = \sum_{i = 0}^{\beta} r_i p^i \equiv r_0 \mod p$$
Hence the desired result:
$$|X| \equiv |\operatorname{Fix}(G)| \mod p$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof seems correct to me. Shortly, the orbit equation reads:
$$|X|=\left|\operatorname{Fix}(G)\right|+\sum_i[G:\operatorname{Stab}(x_i)]$$
where the $x_i$'s are representatives of the non-sigleton orbits. Since $[G:\operatorname{Stab}(x_i)]$ is a *proper* power of $p$ for every $i$, then $|X|\equiv\left|\operatorname{Fix}(G)\right|\pmod p$.